# The order of a $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix mod $ p $

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

This is a question I found in an old textbook in group theory:

> We are asked to prove the order of any matrix $ A $ in the group of $ 2 \times 2 $ invertible matrices over $ F_p $ where $ p $ is a prime, $ A \in \text{GL}(2,F_p) $, divides either $ p^2-1 $ or $ p^2-p $.

I know that the order of this group is $ (p^2-p) (p^2-1) $ thus the order of the matrix must divide it by Lagrange, but the question asks for something stronger. This is obviously true for diagonal matrices and matrices that have one zero. What about a general invertible $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix? How to show its order must divide one of the two factors given? I thought about using the Sylow theorems but nothing comes to mind. Perhaps group actions? The solution eludes me and I would appreciate help on this.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question: given a matrix of order $p-1$, what do you say it divides?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Why such a matrix exists?

Comment: I am referring to the multiplicative order of a general 2x2 matrix modulo a prime p

Comment: @Raito just take $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $F_3$, for example. 
Kroner ok, I just wanted to be sure it can divide both

Comment: Eigendecomposition should help.

Comment: @Zeekless why must an eigendecomposition exist?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 that matrix has order $p-1$, so it is not a counterexample

Comment: @pre-kidney who said it is a counterexample?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 it can divide both but must divide at least 1 of the two

Comment: @kroner You can always get an eigendecomposition by embedding $F_p$ into something bigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Jordan normal form of $A$ over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$. There are two cases: either $A$ is diagonalizable, or there is a single Jordan block.

First consider the diagonalizable case. Then both eigenvalues are elements of $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ and hence $A^{p^2-1}$ is the identity.

Next consider the "single block" case. Then $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form in the other answer, and similar reasoning applies.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why in the diagonalizable case must the eigenvalues be in $F_{p^2}?

Comment: Because they are roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is a degree $2$ polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 2):

Let be $A \in GL(2, F_p)$.

We'll treat three cases:

1. $A$ is diagonalizable over $F_p$.
2. $A$ is not diagonalizable over $F_p$, but there is an eigenvalue $a \in F_p$ (it must be repeated and the dimension of eigenspace must $1$).
3. $A$ is not diagonalizable over $F_p$ and there are no eigenvalues over $F_p$.

If $A$ is diagonalizable over $F_p$, you can say:

\begin{equation*}
A \sim \begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

For some $a, b \in F_p$.

Thus:

\begin{equation*}
A^{p - 1} \sim \begin{bmatrix} a^{p - 1} & 0 \\ 0 & b^{p - 1} \end{bmatrix} = I_2
\end{equation*}

$A$ has order $p - 1$.

Otherwise, let's say $A$ is not diagonalizable over $F_p$ but have eigenvalues repeated in $F_p$, $\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \{ a \}$, so you have:

\begin{equation*}
A \sim \begin{bmatrix} a & 1 \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Let be $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then:

\begin{equation*}
A^n \sim \begin{bmatrix} a^n & na^{n - 1} \\ 0 & a^n \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

It suffices that, if you denote $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ the multiplicative order of $a$ in $F_p$, that $n \mid \mathrm{ord}(a)$ and $n \mid p$, thus: $n \mid p(p - 1) = p^2 - p$.

When you don't have any eigenvalues over $F_p$, that is, when your polynomial has no roots over $F_p$, then you can always have ones over $F_{p^2}$, thus, your order is $p^2 - 1$ because you're again in the case where $A$ is diagonalizable (over $F_{p^2}$ this time.)

In all cases, you either divide $p^2 - 1$ or $p^2 - p$.

Comment: The reasoning is incorrect, $A$ can be diagonalizable over the algebraic closure in which case all we can say is that $a,b\in\mathbb F_{p^2}$.

Comment: @Raito thanks for the answer but if A is not diagonalizable why must it be similar to the matrix you wrote with 1 zero?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form although be careful since he should be applying it to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ (as it only applies to algebraically closed fields)

Comment: @pre-kidney I didn't use JNF? If $A$ is not diagonalizable over $F_p$, we can diagonalize it over $F_{p^2}$? To which case do you refer to?

Comment: If you didn't use JNF, then how do you answer @kroner's question?

Comment: @kroner Either $A$ is not diagonalizable but have roots in $F_p$ and thus you can take one eigenvector and complete your basis to get this form, either you have no roots in $F_p$ and thus you have to go over $F_{p^2}$.

Comment: @pre-kidney I just consider when you're (1) diagonalizable over $F_p$ (2) you have an eigenvalue in $F_p$ but not diagonalizable (double roots) (3) No eigenvalue in $F_p$

Comment: I think the reasoning and exact properties you are using should be stated more clearly in the answer... also in your answer, you should be precise when you say "diagonalizable" over which field you are working.

Comment: @pre-kidney Edited, thank you for your feedback

Comment: @Raito why must the eigenvalues be in the extension $ F_{p^2} $?

Comment: @kroner You want to look at the splitting field of your irreducible characteristic polynomial which is of degree 2, such a field is of degree 2 over $F_p$, $F_{p^2}$ is a field of degree 2 over $F_p$, so you're certain you'll have eigenvalues over $F_{p^2}$, we also know we will be in the first case because this extension is separable.