# Finding the order of a 2x2 matrix mod n when n is NOT prime

Tags: matrices, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Given a $2\times 2$ matrix $A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb Z)$, if $\det(A)$ is relatively prime to $n$, then we can find a $k$ such that $A^k\equiv I\pmod n$. Let us denote the smallest positive $k$ with this property by $\operatorname{ord}_n(A)$.  I wish to understand how this changes for a fixed $A$ and variable $n$.  By the CRT, If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $\operatorname{ord}_{mn}(A)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}_m(A),\operatorname{ord}_n(A))$.  This reduces the problem to understanding $\operatorname{ord}_q(A)$ where $q=p^k$ is a prime power. One can [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3278216/9863) $\operatorname{ord}_p(A)$ divides either $p^2-1$ or $p^2-p$. Further, if you know $A^m=I \pmod{p^k}$, then $A^m=I+p^k B \pmod{p^{k+1}}$ for some (potentially zero) matrix $B$, and then $A^{pm}=I \pmod{p^{k+1}}$, so either $\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k+1}}(A)=\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k}}(A)$ or $\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k+1}}(A)=p\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k}}(A)$.

Are there any other ways one can zero in on this problem in general? Are there good conditions for when $\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k+1}}(A)=\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k}}(A)$ vs $\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k+1}}(A)=p\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k}}(A)$?

My interest is in a specific matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 7 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
which is particularly nice, so there may be a more specialized or ad hoc approach here, which I would be interested in as well,

Comment: If we consider instead the matrix $A = ((1,1),(1,0))$, then the primes $p$ such that the order of $A$ mod $p$ equals the order of $A$ mod $p^2$ are known as Wall--Sun--Sun primes. It is an open question if such prime numbers exist. Heuristics from number theory predicts that they exist but are very rare.

Comment: Of course this may not be relevant as you're asking about a different matrix, but given that this question has been posed over a year ago without developments it may very well be that this is a very hard problem.